# Express + React + Heroku can't find a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

i want to get my app working on Heroku, But there is on problem. Heroku server can't find the images. On developmnt everything is working correctly. Images are loaded propertly. On heroku everything works correctly. Asking for json /api/articles gives in result json. Router also working. But images gives not found. In  tag and fetch() .

code => https://github.com/bartek-fecko/cinema-app

The image file exists on heroku(i looked to the bash on heroku.com)

```
var express = require('express');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));

app.use('/api', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/assets/images')));//i'm sending a file

app.get('/images/:fileName', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `/assets/images/${req.params.fileName}`)); //here also i'm sending a file
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

```
                  <P.Wrapper>
                     <img src="spider-man-far-from-home.jpg" alt="no img"/>
                     <img src="/images/spider-man-far-from-home.jpg" alt="no img"/>
                  </P.Wrapper>
```

I'm getting a 404 error. And  I tried everything and it doesn't work. The same for fetching fetch('/images/ ...') and so on.

Comment: can you try `import src from './spider-man-far-from-home.jpg';` and then `<img src={src} alt="no img"/>`

Comment: I don't know what to do. Importing src from image? image is not in the same catalog where is componnt located. Image is on the backend server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you are having 2 servers:

1. Backend server (inside `src`)
2. Frontend server (inside `client`)

Since when you are starting them, they are of different servers, meaning that they either would be running on different IPs or the same IP but different Ports.

This means that your fetch of the image in the client's `App.tsx` would most likely be referencing the wrong host.

```
fetch('/images/spider-man-far-from-home.jpg')
```

Try using a full URL with both Host and Port in the `fetch` method and see if it works for you.

Comment: thx for your comment. Do U have some resources where i can find something similar? because when i'm trying to give it a full path I get an error: " TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

Comment: fetch('http:/localhost:8080/images/spider-man-far-from-home.jpg') gives me 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/localhost:8080/images/spider-man-far-from-home.jpg' 404 (Not Found) 0_0 but for now i've only tested dev.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. woow. It's working now. The problem was exactly like Yee Hui Poh said. So in production i have to fetch to locallhost:8080/images/spider-man-far-from-home.jpg
where 8080 is backend server.